# Didn't show the clock and slowness

Tags: graphics, wingpanel, time

This was noticed today, My system doesn't show the clock(I took a Screen-shot), I run it on an HP Laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo and 3 GB of ram(DDR2).

How I fix to show the clock ?

[image: My Desk]

Comment: Please split the slowness issue into a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling it:

**`sudo apt remove wingpanel-indicator-datetime`**

**`sudo apt install wingpanel-indicator-datetime`**

That will remove and re-install the date "indicator" of the menu bar (known as `wingpanel`). Are you still having this issue in Loki?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to reinstall indicator-* apps? one of them should bring back clock, but idk which one is responsible for clock. I hope this helps.

Comment: the syntax is ?  sudo reinstall indicator-* apps

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is just deactivated. I've experienced random changes in the settings too, even though not with the clock. You might want to try to change the settings with dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then open dconf-editor and open the path com - canonical - indicator - datetime. There you'll find an option "show-clock" (and plenty more settings...), just tick it and it should work